# Query is failing to execute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, repository

I have a feeling the answer is going to be something super simple, but I've been hitting a mental block for some reason. I have a project I am working on that uses a MVVM pattern that includes entity framework and has a repository implemented. I created a DTO that only contains 3 properties representing fields within a certain Entity that I have. The DTO is named `ParticularGroupDto` and looks super simple:

```
public class ParticularGroupDto : BasicModelBase
{
    private string _groupName;
    private Guid _groupId;
    private Guid? _managerUserId;


    public string GroupName
    {
        get { return _groupName; }
        set { SetValueAndNotify(() => GroupName, ref _groupName, value); }
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid GroupId
    {
        get { return _groupId; }
        set { SetValueAndNotify(() => GroupId, ref _groupId, value); }
    }
    public Guid? ManagerUserId
    {
        get { return _managerUserId; }
        set { SetValueAndNotify(() => ManagerUserId, ref _managerUserId, value); }
    }
}
```

Within my `Repository.Group` file I've got a method:

```
public ParticularGroupDto GetParticularGroup(Guid id)
{
    var manager = DevForce.CreatePrimeEntities();
    IEntityQuery<ParticularGroupDto> query = from k in manager.Groups
                                               where k.GroupId == id
                                               select new ParticularGroupDto
                                               {
                                                   GroupName = k.GroupName,
                                                   GroupId = k.GroupId,
                                                   ManagerUserId = k.ManagerUserId
                                               };

    IEnumerable<ParticularGroupDto> list = query.Execute();
    ParticularGroupDto firstParticularGroupDto = query.FirstOrDefault();
    return firstParticularGroupDto;
}
```

Which I want to simply execute this query that I've got but when it hits `query.Execute();` I get `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

Any ideas on what the issue is here? Much appreciate for taking a look!

***UPDATE***
I also need to mention that the method that passes the "id" parameter here is as follows:

```
 ParticularGroup = Repository.GetParticularGroup(CurrentEntity.GroupId);
```

It just simply grabs a guid that resembles a GroupId for the CurrentEntity that has been loaded (in this case it's the GroupId from the Group entity). I did verify that it is being passed properly by debugging it as well.

Comment: InnerException: null

Message: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo'.